# OData [JsonConverter] attribute serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, odata, json

I am trying to use the default .Net serialization methods when serving OData via EntitySetController.
When using:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Stam { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public TestClassB TestClassB { get; set; }
}

public class TestClassB
{
    public int Ids { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The result of calling GET

```
{
 "odata.metadata":"http://**MyHost**/odata/$metadata#TestClassA","value":[
     {
    "TestClassB":{
      "Ids":110,"Name":"Bla"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

Which works great with the DataContract Attributes.

However, when trying to use the [JsonConverter] attribute:

```
public class TestClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Stam { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyFormatter))]
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public TestClassB TestClassB { get; set; }
}

public class TestClassB
{
    public int Ids { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyFormatter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The JsonConverter is completely ignored. (the MyFormatter class is never created).
Any idea how to make it work?